# Should we disallow answers suggesting to NOT use the Pi for a particular purpose?

Tags: discussion

I was browsing through some previously asked questions on the lines of “How do I use the Pi for X job?”

Many answers on such questions suggested that “the Pi won’t be suitable for such a project,” “it is too tedious to set up," "you better buy a dedicated device," etc.

Seeing that this is a Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange, should we disallow such answers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a word, no.

If the answer is not a good one, it should be downvoted.  Questions can be on- or off-topic for the site, but ultimately as long as an answer addresses the question, it shouldn't be removed or disallowed.  This site focuses on Raspberry Pi usage, but it wouldn't be constructive if we artificially enforced pigeon-holing solutions.

A good answer of this kind should likely be accompanied by a recommendation for an alternative.  As with **all** answers, a one-line response is not a good answer.  A good answer along these lines [will have some explanation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/352/20).

In addition, "the Raspberry Pi isn't suitable" may be correct, and sometimes it may even be the best answer, but perhaps the accepted answer will be a way of achieving the task using the Raspberry Pi, even if using this device isn't optimal.

Comment: Seconded by me.